# spring data, PagingAndSorting repository, Sort based on (nested) attribute value of class type

Tags: java, spring-boot, sorting, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a PagingAndSorting repository for a simple application which consists of Persons.
A simple sort for a property like age works well...

```
Sort sort = Sort.by("age").ascending();

for (Person p : personRepository.findAll(sort)) {
    log.info(p.toString());
}
```

I want to sort persons by lastName as well. But I dont create two attributes for first and last name. I created a class Name which holds first and last name and make an name attribute of this type in Person...

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    // ...  
@Convert(converter = NameAttributeConverter.class)
@Column

private Name name;
    // ...
}

public final class Name implements Comparable, Serializable {
      // ...
      private String firstName;
      private String lastName;
      // ...
}

public class NameAttributeConverter implements AttributeConverter<Name,String> {
 {
        String firstName = attribute.getFirstName() == null ? " " : attribute.getFirstName();
        String lastName =  attribute.getLastname() == null ? " " : attribute.getLastname();

        return  firstName+" "+lastName;
    }

    public Name convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        if(dbData!=null && dbData.split(" ").length > 0) {
            String fname = dbData.split(" ")[0];
            String lname = dbData.split(" ")[1];

            return new Name(fname,' ',lname);
          }

          return null;
    }
}
```

How can I sort by lastName (or firstName)? Something like

```
Sort sort = Sort.by("name").ascending();

for (Person p : personRepository.findAll(sort)) {
    log.info(p.toString());
}
```

executes and brings no error (e.g. persons are printed on console) but doesnt work like expected.

It sorts ascending using the firstName (dont no why).

How can I acieve a sorting based on the lastName attribute of the class name?

Thanks and regards

Comment: @AbinashGhosh I add the converter class in the question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring data JPA: find by column of custom class type's member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61054549/spring-data-jpa-find-by-column-of-custom-class-types-member)

Answer (score 1):

You are storing `name` column's data as `firstName+" "+lastName` in database.

So JPA sort data by name means sort by `firstName+" "+lastName`.

If you define firstname and lastname in database separate column then its possible to sort by lastname also. 
You can follow my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61054549/spring-data-jpa-find-by-column-of-custom-class-types-member) for solve this issue.